# Images from ImageField in Django don't load in template

Tags: python, django, image, django-templates, django-models

I'm building a gallery using Django(1.5.1) on my local machine. In my Album model I have a `ImageField`. There is a view to show all images of an album. It works well, but at the end images don't show up. There's border of images as you can see but images don't load.

#### screenshot

[image]

#### models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
 ###  
class Album(models.Model):   
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='albums')
 ###
class Image(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/albums/')
```

#### views.py

```
def detail(request, album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
    return render(request, 'gallery/detail.html', {'album': album})
```

#### detail.html

```
<h1>{{ album.title }}</h1>
{% for image in album.image_set.all %}
  <a>  <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" height="420"></a>
{% endfor %}
```

If this is my album address: `http://localhost:8000/gallery/1/`

Then image URL is:`http://localhost:8000/media/images/albums/photo_4.JPG (I get 404 when enter it in browser)`

This media root and url:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'    
MEDIA_URL = '/localhost:8000/media/'
```

My media root has *777 permission*.

What should I do now? Where is the problem?

Comment: It seems the server return a Not Found response when requesting the images. Can you inspect image element in the browser and post what is the address in the image `src` attribute?

Comment: Edited my question with more info about urls and root settings.

Comment: That's weird, it should've been `/media/images/albums/photo_4.jpg`. Try to manually, in the browser, type this address `http://localhost:8000/media/images/albums/photo_4.jpg` and see if it shows the image. That should be the correct address. Also in the code, write the `img` tag like this `<img src="/{{ image.image.url }}" height="420">` with a slash character before the url. OK, see if something of this works.

Comment: http://localhost:8000/media/images/albums/photo_4.jpg url doesn't show image. I get 404 error. But "/" in img tag is a good idea. The URL is seems correct. But still images don't load.

Comment: Did you try what my answer says? `MEDIA_ROOT='/media/'`

Comment: Yes. It didn't change anything.

Comment: I edited the answer, I wrote it wrong, it's MEDIA_URL the one which needed to be updated, MEDIA_ROOT was fine, sorry

Comment: Yes. I realized that, and changed ROOT_URL. But as I said, there isn't any image yet. I edited my question with new root and urls.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28837/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-sheshkovsky)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have a clue on what's the problem. `MEDIA_URL` should be like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT='<the full path to your media folder>' (i.e: '/home/ike/project/media/')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

Note the slash character at the beginning. That is because media is a folder in your root server folder and not relative to whatever other url you call it.

And add these lines to the end of your `urls.py` file:

```
# You might need to import static function like this:
#from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

You can check the following documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files

Hope this helps

Comment: I  get an error as staticfiles_urlpatterns not defined. Any Idea?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: Add this line in your `urls.py`: `from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
`

Comment: I'm getting 'name 'static' is not defined'

Comment: @AnselZandegran Add this: `from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static`

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the dev server then you need to add something to your urls.py to make django serve the media files, cf:

1.4.x : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#serving-other-directories
1.5.x: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user

Comment: @Sheshkovsky : Do yourself a favor and go _read_ theses links.

Answer (score 3):

Check in your **settings.py** you have define `MEDIA_ROOT` and 'MEDIA_URL' *(and they are correct)*. The MEDIA_ROOT specifies an absolute folder on your machine where media will be stored.

So for an example:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/myfolder/'
```

This would mean it would look for image at:

```
/myfolder/images/albums/
```

Next in your **settings.py** check your `MEDIA_ROOT` location: i.e.

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost/myfolder/'
```

So your images:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.image.url }}" height="420"></a>
```

This would relate to:

```
http://localhost/myfolder/images/albums/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: image url changes to : http://localhost:8000/media/http://localhost:8000/media/images/albums/shot.png when I change MEDIA_URL and add it to src. But it was fine when MEDIA_URL = ''. So it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: MEDIA_URL needs to be a URL that leads to that same directory path. {{ MEDIA_URL }} is unnecessary when using the url attribute, since it automatically appends MEDIA_URL but you do need to set a {{ MEDIA_URL }} or your image won't show!

Answer (score 2):

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user

```
 from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

you need to add to url pattern to serve uploaded files

Answer (score 1):

Within your *details.html*, change your

```
img src="{{ image.image.url }}" height="420"
```

To

```
img src="your_app/media/{{ image.image.url }}" height="420"
```

I hope this helps. If not I will be glad to provide more details.

Comment: I don't think hardcoding the static url good idea. why not loading the static template tag `{% load static %}` or using `{{ STATIC_URL }}`?

Answer (score 1):

Well I know this question is old but I solved it right now after prove all options:

1. settings.py:

```
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

2. urls.py DANGER!!! Here one of my errors was that I used my_app/urls.py... If you want to use my_app/urls.py you need to add "/namespace_name{{ image.image.url }}" to img' src:

```
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    from django.conf import settings

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

3. Your template, detail.html

```
    img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"
```

NOTES:
Yo don't need MEDIA_URL, be careful with the '/' because image.image.url is absolute, so if you use a namespace then you don't need to add the finish slash.

```
    img src="/namespace_name/{{ image.image.url }}"  --> BAD!!!
    img src="/namescape_name{{ image.image.url }}"   --> GOOD!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a little from each of the answers above. I was having the same problem as you. I was getting returns that were being directed from the current /blog/post/(media_url)/image.jpg

In my admin portal I could view it easily and edit it. But on my post.html I was having problems until I added the {{ MEDIA_URL }} --

That is all that I was missing.

I posted my entire section below so that other people could read it and see what they are missing.

```
post.html:

    <label for="id_image">  <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ p.image.url }}" 
    title="{{ p.title }}"> </label>

models.py:

    from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

    upload_location =
    FileSystemStorage(location='/home/pi/djcode/xpcpro/xpcpro/images')

    class Blog(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
        date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
        body = models.TextField()
        image = models.ImageField(
            storage=upload_location, null=True,
            blank=True, width_field="width_field",
            height_field="height_field",)
        height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)

urls.py:

    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
    document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

settings.py:

    MEDIA_ROOT = "/home/pi/djcode/xpcpro/xpcpro/images/"
    MEDIA_URL = "/images/"
```