# Django uploaded image cannot display in template

Tags: django, templates

I am new to Django and encounter the problem of image rendering in template.
Here is my template code:

```
{% for project in projectList %}

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="preview">
          <div class="image">
            <a href="#"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ project.photo }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ project.name }}"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="options">
            <h3>{{ project.name }}</h3>
            <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
            <div class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Preview</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}
```

and I have set MEDIA_URL as following:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media/').replace('\\', '/') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

But the image did not appear in the webpage, can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{project.photo}}` should be `{{project.photo.url}}`

Update:

```
<a href="#"><img src="/{{ project.photo.url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ project.name }}"></a>
```

And ensure that the webserver is set so that requests made to the MEDIA_URL are actually retrieved from the MEDIA_ROOT folder.

If you want to let Django resolve the MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL add the following lines to your root urls.py.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static 
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns 

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() 
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Source: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28837/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-sheshkovsky

Comment: I just tried that but still cannot work. in the element inspection, the src is "media/projectimg/project1.jpg" yet still not displayed.

Comment: Well then the link is correct, but the webserver isn't forwarding it to the right folder, or isn't looking on the right location. What server are you using?

Comment: i am using sqllite. btw I am also using the STATIC URL for static image, could this be the problem?

Comment: webserver, {apache, nginx, manage.py runserver} because the webserver is failing to link that it should load a file instead of an url. You might want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196603/images-from-imagefield-in-django-dont-load-in-template and http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28837/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-sheshkovsky since they have a problem very similar to yours.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I add a block of code from your link and it works!! Thank you!