# Django : extract image from database and display in template

Tags: python, django, web, pycharm

I am beginner in django so struck at a thing, that i can't find out how to do.
I want to display an image that is stored in database to my template. Images are uploaded to folder 'static/img' .

this is my database:

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
content_brief = models.TextField()
content_major = models.TextField()
img_brief = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/img')
image_major = models.ImageField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
publish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


def publish(self):
    self.publish_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

this is my template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="panel panel-lg panel-custom">
                    <div class="panel-heading post-heading1">
                        <img src="{{ post.img_brief.url }}">
                    </div>
....
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

My views.py :

```
def home_page(request):
    posts =   Post.objects.filter(publish_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('publish_date').reverse()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

settings.py is updated with TEMPLATE_DIRS , STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL.

Comment: So, what happens? Does the image show? Does the rendered template have the right value for the img src?

Comment: image doesn't show

Comment: "Does the rendered template have the right value for the img src?"

Comment: yeah that is correct .... do i need to add media url and media root attributes to settings.py for media location ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing that i was missing that MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT.
changed these to :-

```
MEDIA_ROOT='<the full path to your media folder>' (i.e: '/home/ike/project/media/')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

and also updated url.py file :-

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
...................
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Reference :- [Images from ImageField in Django don't load in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196603/images-from-imagefield-in-django-dont-load-in-template)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so firstly it will be great if you can **specify** the exact part or **error** you are stuck at.

Secondly, if your only purpose is to **display** the images depending on some condition and **never** ever is your **Web-app user** going to **upload** any image i.e., there is no ***forms*** in which the user is uploading images like Facebook upload or so, then technically you **don't really need** a ImageField in your models.

You can simply store the image name in a ***CharField*** and hence write a function in your ***views*** to build a URL for the same which can be used in your ***templates*** to read the image from your *static/img* directory as you have already specified the static.

Moreover the Django official documentation says that you need to have "Pillow" installed to use ImageField(). 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield

Again, specifying the error or the part you are stuck will help a lot in solving your problem

Comment: there is no error the thing is image doesn't show up. Maybe i am missing something in settings.py or anything in views.py ...

Comment: What does INSPECT ELEMENT in your browser shows you in the "panel-heading post-heading1" div? Is it showing the correct URL of the images for all the divs?

Comment: Have you specified the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL settings in settings.py? 
See this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196603/images-from-imagefield-in-django-dont-load-in-template

Comment: i am trying to submit the images through imagefield to a directory inside project but the case is that the image donot get saved to that directory so when i tried to fetch image it shows blank because image was never saved

Comment: Oh, hence my initial suggestion of not using ImageField until unless your Web-app user is not uploading images to your database like Facebook upload. But nevertheless, by using ImageField, now you know how it works..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="panel panel-lg panel-custom">
  <div class="panel-heading post-heading1">
    <img src="/{{ post.img_brief.url }}">
  </div>
....
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

As you don't use the `{% static "" %}` you need to add the `/` before the url of the picture.

Comment: actually i have correct media directory, but when i upload image using admin , the image donot get saved to that directory that i want so when i extract image it does not show up as image is not saved to desired directory ...

Answer (score 0):

**Option-1:** No need to put .url after post.img_breif.

```
    {% for post in posts %}
      <div class="panel panel-lg panel-custom">
           <div class="panel-heading post-heading1">
              <img src="{{ post.img_brief}}">
           </div>
       ....
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

If still not working use the code below:

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
content_brief = models.TextField()
content_major = models.TextField()
img_brief = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/img')
image_major = models.ImageField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
publish_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


def publish(self):
    self.publish_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def image_thumbnail(self):
        return '<div class="panel-heading post-heading1"><img src="%s"/></div>' % (self.img_brief)
    image_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
    image_thumbnail.short_description = 'Image Breif'

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**template**

```
 {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="panel panel-lg panel-custom">
      {{ post.image_thumbnail }}              
      ....
</div>
{% endfor %}
```