# unable to display Image in a Django Template (using ImageField)

Tags: python, django, django-models

i'm uploading an image from the admin site into the imagefield of the model.i've made the necessary changes in the settings.py and urls.py file and added the media directory in my project. Although the image shows up in the admin site, i get "The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it" error while rendering the template.

here are my files:

template(users.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Here are your users</h1>
        {% if user_list %}
            <ol>
                    {% for user in user_list %}
                <li> User Info</li>   
                    <ul>
                       <li>First Name:{{user.f_name}}</li> 
                        <li>Last Name:{{user.l_name}}</li>
                        <li>Email:{{user.email}}</li>
                        <li>Image:<img src="{{ user.image.url }}"></li>

                    </ul>
                    {% endfor %}
            </ol> 
        {% endif %}    




    </body>
</html>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class User(models.Model):
    f_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    l_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.EmailField()
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures',null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.f_name+" "+self.l_name)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import User

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<em>My Second Project</em>")

def help(request):
    helpdict = {'help_insert':'HELP PAGE'}
    return render(request,'appTwo/help.html',context=helpdict)

def dispUsers(request):
    user=User.objects.order_by('f_name')
    user_dict={"user_list":user}
    return render(request,'appTwo/users.html',context=user_dict)
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for ProTwo project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

print(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5$=@s-e_#2yzh+-nn^r!$0%l0%_n-)n(g-9w7f9b+x#@lrc_%%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'appTwo.apps.ApptwoConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ProTwo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ProTwo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
"""ProTwo URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from appTwo import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('help/', include('appTwo.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/',views.dispUsers,name="users")
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[Here's an image showing my diresctory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Khi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Images from ImageField in Django don't load in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196603/images-from-imagefield-in-django-dont-load-in-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
upload_to='pictures/'
```

Use this in image field
And please check file is storing at pictures directory

Answer (score 0):

Your user model has an optional image field on it. Surely you will have some records now or later that don't have an image associated with a user. Therefore the template as it is now will throw an error. All you have to do is put a conditional into the template to see if the user record actually has an image associated with it.

```
{% if user.image %}
    <img src="{{ user.image.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: in that case none of the images show up..even when i've uploaded one from the admin site

Answer (score 0):

Change your model like this:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/', null=True, blank=True)
```

And check that the images are uploading correctly.